# Use the same List of TableColumns for several identical TableViews

Tags: javafx

I have several TableColumns defined. The problem is that when I want to set the same list of TableColumns for the second TableView, I can`t see nothing at the first TableView.

Code:

```
table1.getColumns().clear;
table1.getColumns().addAll(Arrays.asList(TableColumn1,...));
table2.getColumns().clear;
table2.getColumns().addAll(Arrays.asList(TableColumn1,...)); //if I comment this line everything is OK.
```

How I can use the same Columns for creating identical second TableView?

Comment: A `JavaFX` node can not have two `Parents`. It can only be in one `TableView` at a time.

Comment: What happens if you try `.addAll(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(TableColumn1,...)));`? I am curious.

Comment: @Sedrick I have tried. The same situation. We need create new Columns inside ArrayList

Comment: java naming conventions, please

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by  creating this columns (TableColumn1,...) in function.